# Скопировать выделенную область на экранах

Tags: c#, wpf

Каким образом реализуется копирование области на экране ?

Интересует вариант как в приложении Windows "Ножницы" или как в приложении LightShot и им подобных.

По нажатию на горячую клавишу, затемняется весь рабочий стол (не важно сколько мониторов) и есть возможность выделить область для копирования в буфер.

Просто вырезать кусок по заранее заданным координатам могу, а вот как реализовать инструмент выделения, понятия не имею.

```
private Bitmap VirezPicture(int x,int y,int width,int height) // Вырезаем картинку (1)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847612/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/847617#847617)?

Comment: Если делаете скриншотилку, почему бы не порыться в [исходниках](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX) оперсурсных [скриншотилок](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=screenshot&type=Repositories)?

Comment: вам нужен функционал получения области, например при затемнении вы должны кликнуть мышью на левый верхний и на правый нижний угол, либо использовать выделение, для этого вам нужно использовать перехват событий мышки. Это вам направление, так как пока вопрос очень общий.

Comment: [С чего можно начать](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/master/ShareX.ScreenCaptureLib/Forms/RegionCaptureTransparentForm.cs)